# Retrieving all the values of java.util.regex.Matcher group when star wildcard is present

Tags: java, regex, wildcard

```
Text = "AAA1.0BBB2.2CCC33.3" 
R.Expression = ([A-Z]{3}[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)*
```

Expected output

```
AAA1.0<br>
BBB2.2<br>
CCC33.3<br>
```

`Matcher.group(0)` only returns  `CCC33.3.`

Is there any way that I can get my expected output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just call `matcher.find()` in a while block and remove the first group:

```
String Text = "AAA1.0BBB2.2CCC33.3";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Text);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/JkCeZI)

Note that the period symbol must be double-escaped to be treated as a literal period.

The problem with the capturing group around the whole pattern is that the texts captured are stored in 1 buffer that is re-written each time text is captured. Thus, you only get the last `CCC33.3`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Z]{3}[0-9]*[.][0-9]*
```

Just use this as regex engine always remembers only the last group when multiple continuous groups are captured.